# Getting exception on Testlink - selenium webdriver integration

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to integrate testlink - selenium using Testlink API. My Testlink server is running in Linux. And I am using the following code to connect to TestLink.

```
TestLinkAPIClient apiClient = new TestLinkAPIClient("9a2d8ac43d314c72e9ced2e50b0317a1", URL);
boolean isConn = apiClient.isConnected;
System.out.println(apiClient.connectErrorMsg);
```

Also, I have enabled XML_RPC in config.inc file as follows:

```
$tlCfg->api->enabled = TRUE;
$tlCfg->exec_cfg->enable_test_automation = ENABLED;
```

Still I am getting the following exception :

```
testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIException: The call to the xml-rpc client failed.
    at testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIClient.executeXmlRpcMethod(TestLinkAPIClient.java:1266)
    at testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIClient.execXmlRpcMethodWithCache(TestLinkAPIClient.java:1195)
    at testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIClient.getProjects(TestLinkAPIClient.java:726)
    at com.payoda.appviewx.core.APITest.reportResultOnFailure(APITest.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:786)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientException: Failed to parse servers response: Expected methodResponse element, got html
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.readResponse(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:177)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:145)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:94)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.java:44)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:53)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:166)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:157)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:146)
    at testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIClient.executeXmlRpcMethod(TestLinkAPIClient.java:1232)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 7; Expected methodResponse element, got html
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.parser.XmlRpcResponseParser.startElement(XmlRpcResponseParser.java:98)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.readResponse(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:175)
    ... 26 more
```

Please suggest me on the mistake.

I saw a suggestion but couldn't work on the implementation since I don't know the exact implementation. Kindly refer this -> https://discussions.nessus.org/thread/3918.